# Navigation bar in line with logo

Tags: html, css, shopify

I need help with the navigation, to get it in line with the logo. Basically in between the logo and currency button.

Is there an easy way to achieve it instead of messing around with divs and many css adjustments?

My knowledge of html is pretty basic so seeking for help here. Thanks!

[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guNxC.png)

```
<header class="main-header">

<div class="bg" style="display: none;"></div>

<div class="row top">

<div class="columns">

<div class="search-account columns">

</div>

<div class="bottom-row">

<div class="row">

</div>

<div class="main-menu-dropdown-panel">

<div class="row"> </div>

</div>

<div class="mobile-menu">

<div class="row">

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic template you can use.

```css
header h1,
ul,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul {
  float: right;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: 100;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 100;
}
a:hover {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```